# How can I remove or change the tooltip of an icon

Tags: headers, tooltip

I've been using Education Base Pro theme and have been trying to change the tooltip of an social media icon because the options displayed do not have the one i needed (anchor), so what i did was replace the icon image of one i do not use (tumblr) with css:

[image]

But when you hover it keeps displaying the Tumblr name, **Any sugestion in how with css change this name? or completly remove them for every element of the page**

Comment: You'll have to find the code that generates it, which is probably in your theme. Can you search all of the theme files for the word Tumblr?

Comment: Or your theme might support custom social media links anyway. I'd ask the theme authors about this too.